# What is the difference between full and only futures?

Tags: futures

If you look at instrument name for listed on various futures exchange you often see

Gold Only1214

Gold Full1214

What is "Full" and "Only" mean? The price listed is the same and I cannot find a reference to this convention anywhere?

(Please and Thank you.)

Comment: Which exchange do you see this on?

Comment: Gold instruments above are from comex, but CBOT has it for different instruments also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite sure I heard it in reference to trading sessions.  Gold full (trading session) is CME Globex.  Gold only (open outcry) is just the floor session.

The prices will differ when the floor session is closed.

Comment: This sounds reasonable... Thank you. I'd upvote if I could :)